# Scheduling Azure Alerts by Action Group

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-alerts

I am trying to schedule my azure alerts , which runs for every five minutes by query and if condition met, it triggers an email via action group.
what my requirement is to stop email alerts on weekends, I have tried ***azure action processing rules*** but it is not working at all.
where am I wrong couldn't figure it out, can anyone suggest that which approach would be better and how to do that and does action processing rules works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To suppress notifications for your alerts would be to use the   [Alert Processing Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-action-rules?tabs=portal) feature, which is currently in ***preview***.

The Alert processing rules that modify the fired alerts themselves as they are being fired. You can use alert processing rules to add [action groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/action-groups) or remove (suppress) action groups from your fired alerts. In your requirement you could use Suppress.

Suppress approach has some limitations:

- You could disable the relevant alert rule at the beginning of the
  maintenance window. Once the maintenance is over, you can then
  re-enable the alert rule. However, this approach is only practical if
  the scope of the alert rule is exactly the scope of the resources
  under maintenance. For example, a single alert rule might cover
  multiple resources, but only one of those resources is going through
  maintenance. So, if you disable the alert rule, you will miss valid
  alerts on the remaining resources covered by that rule.
- You may have many alert rules that cover the resource. Updating all
  of them is time consuming and error prone.
- You might have some alerts that are not created by an alert rule at
  all. In all these cases, an alert processing rule provides an easy
  way to achieve the notification suppression goal.

You can add your Suppression alert rule to disable the notification. I have disabled the Email Notification on weekends which follows

[image]

Refer [Document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/scale-action-groups-and-suppress-notifications-for-azure-alerts/) for more information

Comment: I am doing exactly as above you have done but the alerts are coming after scheduling it,

Comment: I see alerts are disabled for weekends. Please refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-troubleshoot#action-or-notification-on-my-alert-did-not-work-as-expected) and troubleshoot your alert